# Azure Website Mercurial Deployment Error

Tags: azure, mercurial, web, bitbucket

I'm hoping to take advantage of the new deployment support for Azure websites from a Bitbucket Mercurial repository.  I setup my repository for the Azure website and everything is linked correctly.  However, when a deployment is triggered I get the following error:

```
Process 'hg.exe' aborted due to idle timeout.
```

There's no other error in the log.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. But only on one of my sites.

Comment: ... and after making a new check-in to trigger a deployment I get the following error: 

abort: abandoned transaction found - run hg recover!

Comment: I get it on 2 of my sites but a third deploys just fine.

Comment: We have not seen this before. Are the repos public or private? And for a given repo, does it happen consistently if you create new sites? Any chance that you can share a repo for which this happens? Thanks!

Comment: Other question: how big large are those repos?

Comment: I've send you a video showing the problem and a zip file with our repository. The .hg folder is 55MB in our case. Standard MVC with only 450 commits, no database... pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 6):

I think you may be hitting a timeout. I'm not sure why because your repo isn't that large.

Luckily, you should be able to override it. Please try the following:

- In the portal, go to the Dashboard tab, and click 'Disconnect from bitbucket'
- go to the Configure tab
- Create an AppSetting called `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT` and set it to 600 (meaning 600 seconds, or 10 minutes. The default is 3 minutes).
- Go back to the Dashboard tab, and click 'Setup deployment from source control', and relink it to your repo.

We will work on improving things in the future so it just works by default.

Comment: Nice... this worked for me. This should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks David for a quick solution (I've contacted David via Twitter a few hours ago).

Comment: I did that but it didnt work for me. Problem was about server location. North Europe server was giving this errors so i changed it to US based server and it worked well.

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort you put towards looking into this. I've made the changes you suggested but an still getting the same error.

Comment: @Cory, do you know how long it takes to a clone of your repository locally? If it's closer to the 10 minute mark you might want to try raising the value of `command_idle_timeout` to something longer.

Comment: For future reference: This also solves the issue for git deployment. ( `remote: Process 'git.exe' aborted due to idle timeout.` )